# Java Sqlite Gradle

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm pretty new to gradle and java at all..

I have a project which uses sqlite and it runs fine through intellij idea but I can't run it from the terminal, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

I've tried to get process which intellij idea spawns when it runs the project:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=42986 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home/user/my_project/target/classes/main:/home/user/my_project/target/resources/main:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.2/7a3d67f00508d3881650579f7f228c61bfc1b196/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar Main
```

As I see here idea specifies classpath which is the solution but how can I run my .jar file of the project without specifying classpath? I mean can `gradle` generate manifest automatically (because it retrieves sqlite-jdbc from maven `org.xerial` repository successfully) and put valid classpath there?
I want to run it successffully from the terminal.

UPD: I can't it run from the terminal only by `gradle run` command but I can't run the project by `java -jar myproject.jar`.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

group = 'myproject'
version = '0.3'

description = """my project description"""

buildDir = "target"

mainClassName = "Main"

repositories {
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'3.8.1'
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
}


jar {
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": "Main")
}

/* Overwriting distribution tasks: */
task distZip(type:Zip, overwrite:true) {
    archiveName = "$project.name-$version" + '.zip'
    from "target/libs"
}

task distTar(type:Tar, overwrite:true) {
    archiveName = "$project.name-$version" + '.tar'
    from "target/libs"
}
```

Java source code which throws an exception:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Source code? build.gradle file contents?

Comment: The application plugin will automatically make `compile` (and `runtime`) dependencies available when executing the application with `gradle run`. You should be able to verify this by executing Gradle with `--info` log level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by adding sqlite in the classpath of distribution jar file of the project by modifying my `jar` section by this:

```
task copyDependenciesToTarget(type: Copy) {
    println 'Copying dependencies to target...'

    configurations.compile.collect().each { compileDependency ->
        copy {
            with from (compileDependency.getPath()) {
                include '*'
            }
            into 'target/libs/libs'
        }
    }
}

build.dependsOn(copyDependenciesToTarget)


jar {
    manifest.attributes(
            "Main-Class": "Main",
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { 'libs/' + it.getName()}.join(' ')
    )
}
```

Now gradle downloads dependencies and copies them to `libs/` directory.