# SQLite JDBC with Gradle custom runtime image

Tags: java, sqlite, gradle

I've added SQLite in `build.gradle` and am trying to create a custom runtime image using the `org.beryx.jlink` plugin in Gradle 4.10. When I run the image, I receive the error: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387997/java-sqlite-gradle) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901188/sqlite-gradle) deal with a similar issue but not specificically to the runtime image.

I've added SQLite in build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.9.4'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "12"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.20.1'
}

jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'bankstatementprocessor'
    }
}
```

Once I want to connect to SQLite DB in code, I get the error `No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:`

```java
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
```

As verification, I included the following:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

And, I receive the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`

There seems to be a way to fix this issue with Maven as seen [here](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/README.md#hint-for-maven-shade-plugin):

There are no errors when I simply run the project using `./gradlew run`; however, the image does not seem to register the SQLite driver.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve the desired result is to [pick your JDBC driver at runtime](http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/dyn-jdbc.html). I am not a particular fan of this approach since I feel like there should be a cleaner way to this in in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
jlink {
    ...
    forceMerge("sqlite")
    ...
}
```

https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#_methods